# NSCollectionView does not hide in osx

Tags: macos, swift, osx-yosemite, nscollectionview

I used `NSCollectionView` in my application. In certain condition i want to hide and Unhide the `NSCollectionView`. But it will not hide the `NSCollectionView`.

I used the following code

```
 @IBOutlet weak var thumbnailView: NSCollectionView!
 func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    thumbnailView.hidden = true
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(5)
    thumbnailView.hidden = false
}
```

Note: Sleep the thread just for demonstration purpose

Also  Hiding  the `NSScrollView`  is not working.

**EDIT**: I perform same code on `Button Touch up Inside event` i get the same result. It does not hide my `CollectionView`.

```
@IBAction func ButtonnISClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        thumbnailView.hidden = true
        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(5)
        thumbnailView.hidden = false

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are things that are wrong with your code (mostly because you did not provide enough information in your question):

1. Use lowercase strings when naming variables (so change `ThumbnailView` to `thumbnailView`;
2. I don't know where are you writing this code. Is it `NSWindowController`, `NSViewController` or `NSWindow` subclass? Depending on the location, you should write 2nd to 4th lines in different methods (either `windowDidLoad()`, `viewDidLoad()` or `awakeFromNib()`

**Update:** Given your code is in application did finish launching and you are sleeping in that method, you won't see any changes, since the window of your app is presented only after the method has returned (i.e. all code has been executed). I suggest you to move this code into a subclass of either `NSWindowController`'s `windowDidLoad` (I'm not sure about that one) or `NSViewController`'s `viewDidAppear:` method.

Comment: i put my code in func applicationDidFinishLaunching function

Comment: did you connect the outlet?

Comment: i am not sure why i get  this behaviour . at same time i will able to hide or unhide the other view like NSView, progressIndicator